# How can I store data with unpredictable data types in a table?

Tags: database-design, performance, query-performance

I'm currently working on a Headless CMS project and was wondering what approach would be the best for storing "fields" data in the database.

Basically, users would be able to create a content model with fields of various field types including Media, Text, Long Text, Date and Time (Very similar to contentful.com's content model feature). I have designed a database schema and need validation before integrating it into a live database.

[image: Schema]

Comment: There is no magical way to store everything in a database and make it work fast and efficiently. You can store all of this stuff on the hard drive too, you design a database around how you query it and what you're storing. If you don't need to query it, you can effectively store it /dev/null.